# 2D game engine for iPhone or should i create my own game engine

Tags: iphone, game-engine

Hi am starting to create games for the iPhone and am creating a 2D sidescroller game which engine should i use or will it be easier to create my own game engine

Comment: I strongly recommend you take an off the shelf 2D game engine for iPhone development so that you can focus on the game rather than the framework. I have put together a list of 35 [2D iPhone Game Engines](http://mobilegameengines.com/iphone/2d_game_engines) that might be useful.

Answer (score 3):

Because of this

> ... or will it be easier to create my own game engine

I'll assume that you don't have a lot of experience creating game engines or even many games behind your back.

My suggestion don't make engine as your first project or you will never finish. Make a game or two, figure out what you are missing. Maybe nothing, maybe making UI is too slow/hard, maybe rendering is too slow, maybe something else. Then think about creating engine. Maybe you can start with single module to improve the engine you are already using.

Don't think if everyone is writing engine that's the way to go or you will have an edge in front of these people that don't have engine.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Cocos2D](http://cocos2d-iphone.org/), [Marmalade](http://www.madewithmarmalade.com/), or some other engine listed [here](http://maniacdev.com/2009/08/the-open-source-iphone-game-engine-comparison/).

Answer (score 0):

I think one of the best engines is Cocos2D. Fast, clean, clear, many features: http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/

Comment: Ya i heard about that one i am currently looking at coco2d and corona am just wondering if they were any more game engine that i could use

Answer (score 0):

You can use Corona SDK or Torque 2D for the development of 2D games as they have in-build library which make them easier to use.